# why std::filesystem::current_path() returns different variables when im in editor and using .exe

Tags: c++, filesystems

I have my project where i am using filesystem  to retrieve directory of assets.
When i am lunching my program in editor(im using Visual Studio 2019) everything is fine and this code return value of working direcotry of project.

`std::string currentPath = std::filesystem::current_path().string();`

But when i am lunching app from .exe file this line of code returns path that leads to .exe file.
The same directory called $TargetPath in properties in VS.
So my question is why is that happening and how can i resolve this problem.Becouse of that i cannot automatically load assets when lounching app from .exe file

Comment: It returns - current working directory - which can literally be anywhere on the drive. see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path

Comment: The first command line parameter should contain the path to the exe; that is assuming you haven't added the path to the exe to the `PATH` environment variable (or equivalent).

Comment: MS-Window only - for building paths relative to the location of the program, start by calling `GetModuleFileName` with `NULL` and then create absolute paths to your assets. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamew

Comment: A side note is, you might want to copy the assets to the target path anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is why is that happening

It happens because you've configured the editor to set the working directory to one path, while you're running the program with another working directory outside the editor.

> how can i resolve this problem.Becouse of that i cannot automatically load assets when lounching app from .exe file

Here is an approach:

- Store the assets in a path that is relative to the exe.
- Get path to the exe.

  - On POSIX, you can use `argv[0]` from arguments of `main`
  - On Windows, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=msvc-160) recommends `GetModuleFileNameW`
- Get canonical absolute form of that path (make sure that working directory hasn't been changed before this step if the path to exe is relative).
- Get the directory that contains the exe from that canonical path.
- Join that directory path with the asset's relative path to get an absolute path to the asset
- Load the asset using the absolute path.

Comment: "*Join the current working directory with argv[0] from arguments of main.*" Do not do this. `argv` is not (to my knowledge) UTF-8. So if the path contains Unicode characters, this path will not be correct.

Comment: @NicolBolas I had another reason for skipping that step, but why would that be a problem? Does the system give you a path in an encoding that the system doesn't understand?

Comment: I have no idea what Windows gives you when the path isn't convertible to ASCII. But I highly doubt it's something that `path`'s constructor will accept and turn into a valid path. My guess is that it would be some kind of codepage or whatever, and who knows what their `path` implementation will do with that.

Comment: Also MS-Windows _"...argv[0] may not be the executable name..."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=msvc-160

Comment: @RichardCritten & NicolBolas I've adjusted for windows specifics.

Comment: @RichardCritten good point, and I think Visual Studio uses CreateProcess to run your program.  But if I remember correctly, Visual Studio allows you to configure what goes into argv[0] so you can make it correct even if it isn't by default.

Comment: "*Set the working directory to that directory*" - please don't. "*After this step, [the working directory] will always be the directory where the exe is stored*" - not guaranteed, it may change again during the program's lifetime to point anywhere else. NEVER rely on the working directory being anywhere in particular at any given time. "*Load the assets using the relative path*" - please don't. After you determine the path to the EXE's folder, load the assets using absolute paths that are created with the EXE folder path as the root.

Comment: @MarkRansom I was researching NicolBolas comment re Unicode paths and just came across the note.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Are you certain? I thought it would only change if you call `std::filesystem::current_path` or a corresponding system library call. What else could cause it to change? I'll take your word for it and changed the answer.

Comment: @eerorika yes, I'm certain. There are things out of your control that can change the working directory. Besides direct system calls, and libraries that make such system calls. Also various UI controls (open/save file dialogs, etc)

Comment: @RemyLebeau yeah, I've been bitten by the open/save dialog a few times.

Answer (score 2):

Because it gives the current working directory, which is set by the environment calling your program (unless your program explicitly changes it).

So, it does what it's designed to do, [gives the current working directory](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path):

> Returns the absolute path of the current working directory,